# Selenium printing same information repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Hello I am trying to scrape some data from a website that has data in its 'dl' tag here is how the website structure looks

```
<div class="ecord-overview col-md-5">
<h2><span itemprop="name">Donald Duck</span></h2>
dl class="row">
</dd>
<dt class="col-md-4">Email</dt>
<dd class="col-md-8">myemail.com</dd>
</dl>
<div class="ecord-overview col-md-5">
<h2><span itemprop="name">Mickey mouse</span></h2>
dl class="row">
</dd>
<dt class="col-md-4">Email</dt>
<dd class="col-md-8">youremail.com</dd>
</dl>
... data goes on but value differs
```

To scrape this i am using selenium:

my code for scraping

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ThatsThem-record-overview'): # here im scraping name
   #print(Style.RESET_ALL)
   print(Fore.RED + element.text + Style.RESET_ALL)
   #print(Style.RESET_ALL)
   time.sleep(1)
   dl= driver.find_element_by_tag_name('dl') # scraping data under dl tag 
   print(dl.text)
   print('-----------------------')# seperator
```

So what is happening that whenever i execute the program it prints the dl stuff same for every name and data like this

```
donald duck
Email
myemail.com
-------------
mickey mouse
Email
myemail.com
```

I have already tried putting `dl` in for loop the same way i am doing to print name but it prints other things as well that i don't want

what can i do?

Comment: what is the extra data you are getting and what you don't want to print?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_tag_name('dl')` will always return the first matching element. You need to use `element` to locate the `<dl>`s

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ThatsThem-record-overview'):
    dl = element.find_element_by_tag_name('dl') # scraping data under dl tag 
    print(dl.text)
```

Or just locate those elements directly

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ThatsThem-record-overview dl'):
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. Using the *class* `record-overview` should have fetched you all the required data. However it would be better to target the individual *name* and *email* by traversing to the child tags. Additionally inducing *WebDriverWait* will optimize your program performance.

So, ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  names[] = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.record-overview>h2>span")))]
  emails[] = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.record-overview dl.row dd")))]
  for name, email in zip(names, emails):
      print("{} Email is {}".format(name, email))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  names[] = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'record-overview')]/h2/span")))]
  emails[] = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'record-overview')]//dl[@class='row']//dd")))]
  for name, email in zip(names, emails):
      print("{} Email is {}".format(name, email))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```