# error wrong response type | discord python bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

hello im trying to make a email info command but the output from the url is just the page source is there a way to use left and right strings and capture what's inside the string like i put after the response or is it just .json and i wont be able to use this site?

```
@client.command()
async def email(ctx, email):
    url = ('https://thatsthem.com/email/' + email)

    response = requests.get(url)
    name = response.json()['<span itemprop="name">']['</span>']

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Linked names for email " + email, color=0x00ffff)
    embed.add_field(name="Linked Name:", value=f'{name}', inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

i have the correct token at the bottom and import requests etc thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an HTML-parsing library like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML elements out. Also, use `.text` to get the source if a site can't return JSON properly.

Comment: hello, thank you for this it looks like what i need i set the response to .text and i installed and imported beautifulsoup but im a bit confused on how i will parse the data and make it work any chance you could help? or give me an example? i read there documentation and its a bit confusing, thanks!

Comment: There's many articles about BS, if you want to know how to do something you can probably just google it & find another Stackoverflow post about it. For example if you want to know how to find elements with a particular class, look up "beautifulsoup find element by class". To look at what the source looks like (to see how the elements/ are structured) you can always just print it or check it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

When scraping data you must use headers. When running `requests.get(url)` it returned a 403 but adding the following object as headers to `requests.get(url, headers=headers)` It returned data.

```
headers = {
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751428/selenium-printing-same-information-repeatedly) may help you.